# SAM4S initialization in baby steps

Tags: arm, embedded, microcontroller, atmel

This question may be so obvious it is stupid but I am failing to come up with an answer for it.

I am trying to make a simple makefile project for the sam4s xplained board from Atmel.

I am new to ARM and am feeling a bit lost in how to get stuff to work. Here is what I do trying to get the LEDs to work:

```
 /* Enable clock for PIOC. */
 PMC->PMC_WPMR = PMC_WPMR_WPKEY_PASSWD;
 PMC->PMC_PCER0 = PMC_PCER0_PID13; /* PIOC clock enable. */

 /* Enable output for LED. */ 
 PIOC->PIO_WPMR = PIO_WPMR_WPKEY_PASSWD; /* Enable writing to registers. */
 PIOC->PIO_PER = PIO_PER_P10 | PIO_PER_P17;  /* Enable pio 10, 17. */               
 PIOC->PIO_OER = PIO_OER_P10 | PIO_OER_P17;  /* Set pio10 and 17 as output. */ 
 PIOC->PIO_SODR = PIO_SODR_P10;          /* Set pio10. */                         
 PIOC->PIO_CODR = PIO_CODR_P17;          /* Clear pio17 . */
```

But absolutely nothing happens. Am I missing something?

There should be user LEDs at PIOC 10 and 17.

Board schematics: 
http://www.atmel.com/webdoc/sam4s16xplained/sam4s16xplained.boardScematics.section_ggo_tyg_xf.html

Comment: Not sure about the SAM, but for most other Cortex-M MCUs, the registers for clock enable, port direction, etc. contain single bits for different functions. So you have just to change these bits, not overwrite the complete register contents. Use `|=` and `&= ~` (or normal assignment with the corresponding logical operators) unless you are absoultely sure you want to change the whole register contents at once. Otherwise you might disable clock for other (required) peripherals. The output set/reset registers are normally an exception as they do this in hardware.

Comment: Also: can you read the values written from the registers? Did the hardware really execute the writes?

Comment: @Olaf The registers used above are all write-only. The datasheet specifies that writing a 0 has no effect which is the reason for using them as I do above. There is a seperate "clear"-register for disabling. As for reading the registers I have not gotten OpenOCD working for the board yet so I am working blind so far otherwise I would have checked this.

Comment: Hmm..  interesting. Just had a peek at the datashet. Yes, they really seem to have these function seperated for all registers; nice feature; most other ARM-MCUs just have this for the output register. However, you actually _can_ read the register's values. This is just another register for every quad of registers, called "status register" (step back and look at the whole picture). Actually, there is a single register which can be addressed from four adjacent addresses and encode set/reset/read actually; for some registers like the output data register, the status can be both: read and written.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was not in the code but in Atmel's tools used to program the board. I had been using SAM-BA In-system Programmer to program the board but for some reason it failed to change the contents of the flash. Even setting a single manually in the memory view fails.

I instead tried Seggers JLink software and did the following steps:

1. Update the JLink driver on the board using Atmel Studio 6 (this step requires windows).
2. Downloaded the J-Link software package for Linux from Segger: https://www.segger.com/jlink-software.html.
3. Using JLinkExe to program the board, like so:

   1. Make sure JP25 is disconnected - only needed for sam-ba.
   2. Connect via usb with the jtag connector.
   3. Start JLinkExe

In the JLink terminal do:

```
JLink> device at91sam4s16c
JLink> loadbin <target.bin>, 0x400000
```

Sometimes I need to reset the board before it works after programming it. Using the Segger tools debugging also works now. Start gdb server with JLinkGDBServer and connect with arm-none-eabi-gdb using:

```
(gdb) target remote :2331
(gdb) file <target.elf>
```